# Android : onSearchRequested() capture text

Tags: android, search, android-edittext

I am developing a sample for searching functionality.
I have used onSearchRequested() and on calling it, I get an edit box in which I can enter
the search parameter.
What I would like to do is, I want to capture the text entered in the edit box as I would like to send it to another activity.

Generally for an editText that is defined by us , we can access it using its 'id'.
But, since in the case of onSearchRequested(), the editText is creted automatically , so how can I access and capture the text typed in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation regarding [creating a search interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html). Part of the documentation is an example on how to set up a SearchableActivity that is called with the query entered by the user and that should do the searching and showing the results. I guess this is exactly what you want.

Comment: you can store a String variable for the text(entered in editText field ) in CommonObject class, then easily call it in any other Activity.